# Select all checkbox with three states

Tags: user-interface

Remember installing a program for example and you can check individually each item or you can check a 'select all' check-box at the top? And when some lines are checked the 'select all' box has a green fill inside instead of a check or being empty?

What I'm trying to ask is what is the normal behavior for the 'select all' box?

For example if few lines are checked the box is green, now if I click the box everything gets selected, but when I click it again should everything deselect or should the individual boxes remember whether they were checked before I checked 'select all'?

Comment: This question is on-topic from an user perspective but it's too subjective/argumentative. The behavior of deselecting the 'select all' option depends on how it has been written by the developer of the installer. Yes, there are different behaviors. No, there is no single answer.

Comment: Questions about user-interface design and best practices will be better served on this [coming site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface). It can also be answered currently on our sister site dedicated to programming, where I'm migrating your question.

Comment: @Gnoupi Thank you for that, wasn't sure where to post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal behaviour:

When you click the 'select all' box *again* everything should deselect. (This is the only way to deselect everything). If the user wants to revert back to how it was (the individual sub selections) then they either have to do this manually, or cancel and start over.

Comment: Ok, that was what I thought. (About deselecting everything I was thinking the user might click yet again on 'select all' but that is probably just confusing, I just wanted to now how the normal behavior is so that users will know what to expect when clicking 'select all').